# How do you redirect HTTP to HTTPS and remove .html in the same rewrite rule?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way that we can remove .html file extension and move http to https in the same redirect rule so that we do not have multiple redirect chain on the same page.

http -> https -> remove .html

this leads to take more loading time and also has two redirects.

here is htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
#force https+www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


#Remove .html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Could you please share your .htaccess file what you have tried in your question.

Comment: Kindly post this in your question, comments are not meant to post attempts, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single redirect rule like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine on

#force https+www and remove .html
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /[^.\s]+\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:\.html)?$ https://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect !! you are a life saver !